# Is the order in which function arguments are resolved guaranteed?

Tags: javascript

say I have this:

```js
function write3(a, b, c) {
  document.write(a + " " + b + " " + c);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var i = 0;

write3(arr[i++], arr[i++], arr[i++]);
```

It results in 1 2 3 as expected, however, I'm not sure that this is guaranteed behavior. Could the arguments passed to write3 hypothetically be resolved in any other order than left to right?

Comment: @Hitmands: What isn't correct about it?

Comment: @Hitmands: Oh, that doesn't mean it's not correct. It's just a superfluous increment unless `i` is going to be needed after the operation.

Comment: @Hitmands Unnecessary operations do not make an example "incorrect."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the order of argument evaluation is guaranteed to be left-to-right.

According to sections [11.2.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3) and [11.2.4](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.4) of the ES5 spec, function arguments are Argument Lists, and Argument Lists should always be evaluated left to right.

Specifically, the function to call gets evaluated, and then the function's arguments are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

> Could the arguments passed to `write3` hypothetically be resolved in any other order than left to right?

No, they will always be resolved left-to-right. This is guaranteed behavior.

I also feel like I should point out that you can call a function with an array of arguments using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
write3.apply(null, arr)
```

. . . or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in ES6+ (may not be supported in all browsers):

```
write3(...arr)
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
function write3(a, b, c) {
  document.write(a + " " + b + " " + c)
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3]

write3.apply(null, arr)

write3(...arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Afterwords. If you use ES6 you can write:

```
write3(...arr)
```